# What to do in case of shim under bucket with no clearance?

Tags: valve, shim

Went to do the valve clearance check on my 1994 Suzuki Katana 600 and was dismayed to find that I have zero clearance on any of the valves...  Even my thinnest feeler gauge won't slip between and it visibly looks like hard contact.  16,000 miles on it and as far as I know this has never been checked.

Is this engine a lost cause?  Or, can I attempt thinner shims and see if I can get some clearance?

Comment: You can possibly mix/match shims to get the right clearance ... still going to require you to get some more shims. Bike is not a lost cause, though. I would think it would just be down on power as you might be getting some leakage past the valves at worst. Maybe do a leakdown test to see if there's anything happening there. Not bad on the intake, but leakage on the exhaust side could cause a burnt valve.

Comment: Is there a performance problem ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 It's got some wonky idle issues that didn't go away after carb overhaul and balancing.  Seems to run well at speed though.  I really expected to measure and find it still in spec  After talking to some other people I'm now concerned that it's going to need valves and seats.  I'm not equipped to do that job and would likely scrap the bike and buy a new one in that situation.

Comment: So does it have a shim in place as standard? If you remove it whats the measurement then?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch i dont know your circumstances but scrapping the bike over a valve job seems excessive. Hang in there. This might be something simple to resolve without major expense

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot It does have a shim in place as standard.  I'll remove them and see what happens I guess.  If it's wearing in this direction though I'm headed towards a valve job I presume.  I don't have the facilities at home to even consider pulling the engine.  Trying to find a local shop that will do this kind of work (or even touch a bike this old) is a challenge.  Combine that with the fact that I only paid $1 for the bike 7 years ago...  Might be easier/cheaper to replace the entire bike (even though I'd prefer not to).

Answer (score 1):

Based on memory of similar bucket shims the process was to remove all shims then measure the gap and do a bit of subtraction to get the required shim thickness.

And also needed is a big supply of shims - last time I did that I was at the main dealer so I had access to the full range... But if you have to order and wait that is not so much fun.

Comment: On this one it's measure existing gap, if in range, do nothing.  If out of range, remove the shim, measure it, do the math for new shim, replace.  Then measure again when done to confirm.